# How to set the name of a form input

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following:

```
$this->Form->input('type', array(
    'options' => array(
        'Blog',
        'Forum',
        'News',
        'Other'
    ),
    'empty' => '(Select a type)'
), array('title' => 'Select your websites type'));
```

However the title doesnt change instead the title is '`type`'. How can I change the title?

Comment: `FormHelper::input` has no third parameter, options as well as attributes go in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming with "title" your referring to the label of the input

```
 $this->Form->input('type', array(
                'options' => array('Blog',
                                   'Forum',
                                   'News',
                                   'Other'),
                  'empty' => '(Select a type)',
                  'label' => 'Select your websites type'));
```

If you are referring to the html attribute "title" and don't mind the label of select, then

```
 $this->Form->input('type', array(
                'options' => array('Blog',
                                   'Forum',
                                   'News',
                                   'Other'),
                  'empty' => '(Select a type)',
                  'title' => 'Select your websites type'));
```

Of course, you can mix those up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the name from `'type'` to something else, just replace `type` in your code:

```
$this->Form->input('NEW NAME HERE', array(
    'options' => array(
        'Blog',
        'Forum',
        'News',
        'Other'
    ),
    'empty' => '(Select a type)'
));
```